# Same E mail address is sending e mails from different servers

Tags: c#, email

I'm using this code to generate emails from c sharp. 
e mails are sending correctly. but when I'm     changing the server IP address, again e mails are  sending through same address.

```
SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("192.168.0.253");
mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new
System.Net.NetworkCredential("FromUsername", "12345");
mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("FromAdderss", "FromName");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("ToAddress", "ToName");
MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);
myMail.Subject = "Test message";
myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
myMail.Body = "<b>Test Mail</b><br>using <b>HTML</b>.";
myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
```

Comment: Do you mean that changing `SmtpClient("192.168.0.253")` to another IP results in the emails still being sent via the original IP?

Comment: How did you check e-mails were sending through same address? Perhaps the 'other' target smtp server uses your 192.168.0.253 as a relay? It is also good practise to send a QUIT after messages are send. mySmtpClient.Dispose() after send. More info about the smtpclient class can be found here: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I cant identify e mails are sending via original IP or not after change it. but any e mails are provided to Fomaddress mails are sending. siva.k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The From field is detached from the IP address. You could in theory use any email address you want even from another totally different domain (this is common with most mail servers). If you want to check the IP address I suggest you check the email headers. There you should find information on how the email was transported.